# neural network and genetic algorithm

Tags: python, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I am working with a complex system, the system has five variables - depending upon values of these five variables, the response of the system is measured. There are seven output variables that are measured in-order to completely define the response.

I have been using artificial neural network to model relationship between the five variables and the seven output parameters. This has been successful so far.. The ANNs can predict really well the output (I have tested the trained network on a validation set of testcases also). I used python Keras/tensor flow for the same.
BTW, I also tried the linear regression as function approximator but it produces large errors. These errors are expected considering that the system is highly non-linear and may not be continuous everywhere.

Now, I would like to predict the values of the five variables from a vector of the seven output parameters (target vector). Tried using Genetic algorithm for the same. After a lot of effort in designing the GA, I still end up getting high differences between target vector and the GA prediction. I just try to minimize the mean squared error between ANN prediction (function approximator) and target vector.

Is this the right approach to use ANN as function approximator and GA for design space exploration?

Comment: What is your objective? Also GA cannot do prediction, it is used for optimization. May be u can find the best combination of five variables which can give the max value in your target variable using GA

Comment: " May be u can find the best combination of five variables which can give the max value in your target variable using GA –"
I am doing this but slightly in a different way. I would like to minimize the error between the target and the predicted variables. The ANN serves as the function approximator. But, this does not seem to work.
I now started thinking if GA can be used or not when the target function is ANN.

Comment: GA is not an approach for function appropriator.  What do you mean by "this does not work". But you mentioned earlier as "The ANNs can predict really well the output"

Comment: Input data ----> ANN ----> output data : ANN is used to build a relationship between input and output.

How to find a set of "input variables" that can produce a specific output "target"? I used GA for this.
target -----> GA -------> input variables 
What do I optimize in GA? it is the mean squared error of ANN output and target. So, how does it work? GA sets an initial population, sends those values to ANN, ANN predicts the output - GA compares ANN output with target - finds mse - repeats until a minimum mse is reached. Hence, GA is used as optimizer and not as function appropriator.

Comment: Is this the right approach to use ANN as function approximator and GA for design space exploration? - Yes. I am not getting, where the issues is now!

Comment: Question: is this approach a good one? what else can be used instead of GA for optimization of a function based on ANN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a good approach to do search space exploration using GA. But designing the crossover, mutation, generation evolution logic, etc. plays a major role in the determining the performance of the Genetic algo.

If your search space is limited, you can use exact methods (which solves to optimality).

There are few implementation in [python-scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#constrained-minimization-of-multivariate-scalar-functions-minimize) itself

If you prefer to go with meta-heuristics,

there is a wide range of options other than Genetic algorithm

Memetic algorithm
Tabu Search
Simulated annealing
Particle swarm optimization
Ant colony optimization